# Cant design pixel perfectly as like my Figma design, Constraint layout cuts out some of my views

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout, figma

I don't get the accurate view as like my Figma design. Constraint layout cuts out some of my views and also is not matching with top Search bar as I designed with Linear Layout. What should I do for pixel perfect design as like my Figma design?

The Figma design of my project:

[image]

Portrait view after run:

[image]

Landscape view after run:

[image]

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/teal_200"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menubar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_white"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="13dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="9dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="265dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape1"
                android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ic_search"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="14dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/search_txtinput"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ic_search"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                    android:hint="Search or type address"
                    android:textSize="13dp"
                    android:paddingStart="13dp"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_white"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="13dp"
                    android:layout_height="13dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_rounded_pg_bg"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            android:paddingStart="19dp"
            android:paddingEnd="19dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fb_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/yt_btn"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/fblogo"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_white">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="8dp"
                            android:layout_height="18dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/fb_logo" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                        android:paddingTop="9dp"
                        android:text="Facebook"
                        android:textSize="12.3dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/yt_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="48dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/fb_btn"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/twitter_btn"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ytlogo"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_white">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="12dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/yt_logo"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="12.3dp"
                        android:text="Youtube"
                        android:paddingTop="9dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/twitter_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingStart="50dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/yt_btn"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/insta_btn"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/twtrlogo"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_white">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="18dp"
                            android:layout_height="14dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/twitter_logo" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                        android:paddingTop="9dp"
                        android:text="Twitter"
                        android:textSize="12.3dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/insta_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="48dp"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/twitter_btn"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/instalogo"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_white">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="21dp"
                            android:layout_height="21dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/insta_logo"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="12.3dp"
                        android:text="Instagram"
                        android:paddingTop="9dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I tested it, and it worked perfecrtly with me, i dont have this margin horizontal as you, try to use invalidate caches and re-run it

Comment: I invalidated the caches and restarted but when I run it into android studio emulator it works fine but when I run it into my android phone it cuts out some of views.

Answer (score 1):

Removed the start padding from each Linear Layout (parents of logos and names), and that solved the problem.
Code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/twitter_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            <!-- android:paddingStart="50dp"[Removed paddingstart] -->
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/yt_btn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/insta_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/twtrlogo"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_white">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="18dp"
                        android:layout_height="14dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/twitter_logo" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                    android:paddingTop="9dp"
                    android:text="Twitter"
                    android:textSize="12.3dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```